# How to use IAM of the host machines inside docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go

I'm setting up a go server in docker on a ec2-machine this server uses the aws-sdk-go module to make calls to AWS api. This binary built from the following code gives certificate issues when running inside container.

The same binary runs fine and gives the expected result when running on host machine.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/autoscaling"
)

func main() {
    svc := autoscaling.New(session.New(), aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-east-1"))
    input := &autoscaling.DescribeAutoScalingGroupsInput{
        AutoScalingGroupNames: []*string{
            aws.String("spark-worker-asg"),
        },
    }

    result, err := svc.DescribeAutoScalingGroups(input)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case autoscaling.ErrCodeInvalidNextToken:
                fmt.Println(autoscaling.ErrCodeInvalidNextToken, aerr.Error())
            case autoscaling.ErrCodeResourceContentionFault:
                fmt.Println(autoscaling.ErrCodeResourceContentionFault, aerr.Error())
            default:
                fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
            }
        } else {
            // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
            // Message from an error.
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Error logs:

```
RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://autoscaling.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: You need to install ca-certificates package in your docker container.
```RUN apt install -y ca-certificates #for ubuntu```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to assign IAM role to docker container, it already using Host IAM tole as host metadata is accessible to Docker container.

> caused by: Post https://autoscaling.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: x509:
>   certificate signed by unknown authority a

The error above is not due to permission, it something missing in your Docker image.

Try to add `ca-certificates` in a docker container.

> Make sure the ca-certificates package is installed on your instance.
>   After installing restart your Go programs.

[AWS SES Error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601404/aws-ses-error-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority)