# aws-sdk-go Error:RequestError: send request failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-go

i am trying to query the aws using aws-sdk-go api call "ListMetricsWithContext()".

it was working fine earlier. but occasionally i get this error .
 following is the error :

Error:RequestError: send request failedncaused by: Post https://monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

what should i do.

i am using a opensuse based image on my machine.

Comment: Maybe related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601404/aws-ses-error-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority

Comment: i have tried installing the ca-certificates on the machine from where i am making api calls , still same error

Comment: I am also getting the same issue @ashishchoudhary. Were you able to resolve the issue? Please let me know. I have installed ca-certificates but still not working